# Stop storyboard in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following very simple setup.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1200">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath 
            Duration="0:0:5" Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)" >
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M-348.26805,-1.3505859E-05 L66.500091,-1.3505859E-05"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:5" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.Y)" >
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M-348.26805,-1.3505859E-05 L66.500091,-1.3505859E-05"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="Animation_Path" Left="3.409" Top="53.412" Margin="202.428,351.761,482.635,360.19" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path x:Name="testpath" Data="M683.91667,287.08333 L816.91635,287.08333" Height="0" Canvas.Left="683.917" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Top="287.083" Margin="247.732,384.5,529.5,384.5"/>

    </Canvas>

    <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="588,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_5"/>
    <Button Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="690,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_6"/>

</Grid>
```

And code behind is like so.

```
   private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        ObjectToMove move = new ObjectToMove();
        Animation_Path.Children.Add(move);

        var sb1 = FindResource("Storyboard1") as Storyboard;
        sb1.Begin(move);

    }
```

This works just fine. I can run the animation and create new object each time the button is clicked. But the issue is when I am willing to stop the animation at some required point.

using `sb1.Stop()` is not doing the trick. I think it has to do because I am adding the new created object as a child to the `animation_path` and this is why I have no control as it starts.

So the question(s) is:

Is it possible to stop the animation in this case..?

What is the best alternetive possible option..?